# Why do I see requests for other websites in my log files?

Tags: asp.net

I've been using the Application_BeginRequest method in my global.asax code redirect non-HTTPS traffic to the HTTPS version of the site by using the following code:

```
If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection = False AndAlso HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal = False Then
    mLog.Info("Application_BeginRequest - redirecting non-HTTPS request to " & "https://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
End If
```

For some reason I frequently see entries for unknown websites like this in the log file:

> Application_BeginRequest - redirecting non-HTTPS request to https://t10.proxy-checks.com/favicon.ico

How can a request for a site that isn't mine be getting to my web server?

Answer (score 0):

Probably people sniffing for vulnerabilities and such.

You A records and CNAME, etc, aren't the only way that a web request can get to your server, those are just pointers that tell people where your server is at.

You can use programs like fiddler to send a web request formatted however you want to whoever you want, if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. If I ping "t10.proxy-checks.com", it doesn't resolve to our website IP (it's some Russian IP address), so if somebody sent a request to it, why would it hit our website?

Comment: They could have sent an http request for that website to your IP address.

Comment: That sounds like a contradiction in terms. How can you craft a request for website A that goes to website B?

Comment: The only thing I can really suggest to see what I am talking about is downloading a program called "Fiddler 4" by telerik and just seeing for yourself. Normally, if you try to go to google.com, http or https assumes that you mean port 80 or 443 respectively, google.com is the dns request, which returns and tells your browser what ip to send the web request to. But, you don't have to send web requests from a web browser and they don't have to be a sane request in order for them to make it to your web server.